# Call function method

Tags: javascript, node.js

why can't I call the getCar () method of my Car function? in class the teacher assigns the app variable to the express () function example: const app = express () and from the app he calls the app.get methods, etc ... Why can't I call the methods of my Car function?

```js
const port = 3003

const express = require('express')
//This function
console.log(typeof express)

const app = express()
//This function
console.log(typeof app)


function Car(model, color, price) {
    this.model = model; 
    this.color = color;
    this.price = price;

     this.changeColor = function(){
        console.log(this);
        this.color = 'Blue';
    }



    this.getCar = function() {
        this.changeColor();  
      return console.log(`Model: ${this.model} Color: ${this.color} Price: ${this.price}` ) ;
    }


}

//app.get() <<<< It's ok
Car.getCar() // It dont's run, LUL
```

Comment: Because you don't call the Car constructor.

Comment: I assume you need to call Car().getCar()

Comment: Car().getCar()
     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCar' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new instance before being able to call the methods:

```js
function Car(model, color, price) {
  this.model = model;
  this.color = color;
  this.price = price;

  this.changeColor = function() {
    console.log(this);
    this.color = 'Blue';
  }

  this.getCar = function() {
    this.changeColor();
    return console.log(`Model: ${this.model} Color: ${this.color} Price: ${this.price}`);
  }
}

var car = new Car('VW Beetle', 'red', '$10.000');
car.getCar();
```

Comment: And why doesn't the express API need to instantiate the object? before calling the method of the function?

Comment: @RafaelF.Ferreira — Because the `express` function isn't a constructor function.

Comment: I know that by instantiating an object I can call the functions, my question is why the express API functions call the methods of the function without instantiating the object ...

Comment: I see, could you explain better with an example?

Comment: Because the `express()` function returns an object with methods, something like this: https://codepen.io/Connum/pen/rNamwNB?editors=1111

Comment: So why when I do console.log (typeof app) the answer is function and not object?

Comment: Because [`"in JavaScript, functions are first-class objects"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions), so the returned object can also be a function: https://codepen.io/Connum/pen/vYEmZLe?editors=1111

Comment: Did this resolve your question or do you need any further information?

Comment: @ConstantinGroß I'm still a little confused friend, I looked at the express API source code and analyzed the createApplication function, it returns app. I still don't understand when my function becomes an object